# SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have the following error in php (Yii2 Framework):

Error:

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException
SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (853322, 395, 4, 2023, 5245.50, 1, null).
The SQL being executed was: INSERT INTO "db"."budget_report_by_project" ("month", "year", "category_id", "currency_id", "project_id", "value") VALUES (4, 2023, 395, 1, NULL, '5245.5') RETURNING "id"
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 23502
    [1] => 7
    [2] => ERROR:  null value in column "project_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (853322, 395, 4, 2023, 5245.50, 1, null).
)


1. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php at line 676
2. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 1307– yii\db\Schema::convertException(PDOException, 'INSERT INTO "db"."budget_r...')
3. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 1168– yii\db\Command::internalExecute('INSERT INTO "db"."budget_r...')
4. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php at line 424– yii\db\Command::queryInternal('fetch', null)
5. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/pgsql/Schema.php at line 646– yii\db\Command::queryOne()
6. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php at line 604– yii\db\pgsql\Schema::insert('db.budget_report_by_projec...', ['month' => 4, 'year' => 2023, 'category_id' => 395, 'currency_id' => 1, ...])
7. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/ActiveRecord.php at line 570– yii\db\ActiveRecord::insertInternal(null)
8. in /var/www/internal_system/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/BaseActiveRecord.php at line 676– yii\db\ActiveRecord::insert(true, null)
9. in /var/www/internal_system/models/BudgetReportProject.php at line 463– yii\db\BaseActiveRecord::save()
457458459460461462463464465466467468469
```

Code:

```
$budgetItem->category_id = $item['category_id'];
$budgetItem->currency_id = $item['currency_id'];
$budgetItem->project_id = $item['project_id'];
$budgetItem->value = $item['value'];
if (!is_null($budgetItem->project_id))
{
    if (!$budgetItem->save())
    {
        $result['error'] = $budgetItem->getErrorMessge();
        return $result;
    }
}
unset($budgetItem);
```

To prevent it, I have already added the following line:

```
if (!is_null($budgetItem->project_id))
```

It should check ID project_id IS NOT NULL and process with saving.
But it seems that the code above (null-check comparison) does not work. If project_id is null, it should return TRUE, so the execution of the following code to save the item will not be performed:

```
if (!$budgetItem->save())
{
        $result['error'] = $budgetItem->getErrorMessge();
        return $result;
}
```

It is wrapped into 'if' block to return error messages if they occures.

I expect that if the project_id value is NULL, I can simply ignore it and avoid adding it to the database. However, it seems that null-check does not work for me in this case.

I have also tried to compare project_id value with NULL and null, with no success.

Can you please advise?

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. `if (!is_null($budgetItem->project_id))` did you mean `if (is_null($budgetItem->project_id))`? Please read your code again and explain what is the role of the each of the 2 `if`, add this information by **Edit**ing the question.

Comment: Hi, thank you. No, I expect that IF project_id is NOT NULL, I can proceed with saving an item into the database. So, it should be !is_null. So, if project_id is null, the function will return true, so the code inside will not be executed.

Comment: Have you first of all checked what `$item['project_id']` actually contained, for a case where you are getting this error?

Comment: Check what is the values of `$budgetItem->project_id` before if (!is_null($budgetItem->project_id)). `is_null()` works for only null values. I suspect you have empty string in `project_id` and letter replaced with null from rules.

Comment: @InsaneSkull you are absolutely right! I have just replaced the first 'if' condition with an empty string check and it works well! `if (!empty($budgetItem->project_id))` and now everything is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you use model's [validation rules](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-validation) (example, required rule for your use case) instead. Read [models massive assignment](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models#massive-assignment) and [model load method](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-base-model#load()-detail).

You can check input with model's validate() or save() method.